# How can I prevent a Node.js child process from running malicious code?

Tags: node.js, npm, child-process

I have a module that uses child_process to run users' code (that I write to a file). I use the following to execute the code and return a stream of the child's stdout.

Now I'd like to prevent users from entering malicious code, such as opening another process to execute commands. But I can't find a library or a good way to do this. Is there a way to prevent a child process from using code with libraries?

```js
const runCodeInChildProcess = (
    challengeId: number,
    userId: string,
    memoryLimit: number,
    timeoutMs: number,
) => {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        // limit max memory to prevent out of memory situations
        let childProcess = spawn('node', [
            `--max-old-space-size=${memoryLimit}`,
            `./src/challenges/sessions/${challengeId}_${userId}.js`,
        ]);

        // todo: prevent injection (library?)

        let setTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            childProcess.kill();
            console.log('timed out: killing child process...');
            reject(executionTimeoutError);
        }, timeoutMs);

        let stdoutChunks: readonly Uint8Array[] = [];
        let stderrChunks: readonly Uint8Array[] = [];

        childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            stdoutChunks = stdoutChunks.concat(data);
        });

        childProcess.stdout.on('end', () => {
            var stdoutContent: string = Buffer.concat(stdoutChunks).toString();
            console.log('stdoutContent ' + stdoutContent);
            resolve(stdoutContent);
        });

        childProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            stderrChunks = stderrChunks.concat(data);
        });

        childProcess.stderr.on('end', () => {
            if (stderrChunks.length === 0) return;
            let stderrContent: string = Buffer.concat(stderrChunks).toString();
            reject(stderrContent);
        });

        childProcess.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error('Failed to start subprocess. ' + err.message);
            reject(childProcessStartError);
        });

        childProcess.on('close', (code) => {
            console.log(
                `exited child_process at ${challengeId}_${userId}.js with code ${code}`
            );
            clearTimeout(setTimeoutId);
        });
    });
};
```

The function is invoked by a module `challengeService` and here's an example of how it should be consumed:

```js
test('should not pass when child process opens more child processes', async () => {
    let execData = {
        challengeId: 1,
        userId: '97kXRneizwRa5WWHZ6BPi2eDJV19',
        userCode: `function SomeMethod(numbers) {
            const { exec } = require('child_process');
            exec('ps -o ppid= $$', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                // do something with ppid
            });
        };`,
    };

    const action = async () =>
        await challengeServiceModule.execute(execData);
    await expect(action).rejects.toThrowError(invalidCodeError);
});
```

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853117/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-the-access-of-child-processes-to-my-system-in-node-js) would help(?)

Comment: You would have to run the other process in a sandboxed VM where the VM controls what level of resources the process is allowed to access, use or modify and it can't escape the sandbox defined for it by the VM.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00! I found this sandboxed vm tool `vm2` that runs untrusted code so that the resources are separated. https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2